# sqlalchemy - remove a label from a column

Tags: google-bigquery, sqlalchemy

I am using sql alchemy to query BigQuery.

I have a subquery and I am trying to dedup it using ArrayAgg

basically it should look like this:

```
SELECT
 t.id,
 ARRAY_AGG (t ORDER BY `time_col` DESC LIMIT 1)[OFFSET(0)].*
 from (
    SELECT ...
  ) t
 GROUP BY t.id
```

I created a compiler function that generates the ARRAY_AGG as I desire.

The problem is, when I try to execute the query, the array agg field gets an automatic label which ruins everything.

Is there a way to just make it use the `*`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I found the answer with the help of my colleague, and wanted to put it here should anyone will ever face this too

We basically generated the following query without the `*` so we got a struct, and wrapped it with another select to extract the fields.

We made a function that wraps the query with this logic and returns something like this:

```
SELECT deduped_record.field_1, ..., deduped_record.field_n
FROM (
    SELECT  dedup_by_field,
            ARRAY_AGG(source_table ORDER BY dedup_time_field DESC LIMIT 1)[OFFSET(0)] AS deduped_record
    FROM (
        SELECT field_1,...,field_n
        FROM table
    )
    GROUP BY dedup_by_field
) AS alias
```

We just get the fields via the alias, instead of the `*`.